# How to represent "groups" in SQL?

Tags: sql, database-design

I code just as a hobby, but always try to learn the "proper" way of doing things. I am very novice when it comes to SQL, and thus I want to give extra background in case I may be approaching the problem completely wrong.

First, I will have a list of "switches" that can be interacted with. The name of each switch will be unique. The DB will need to know how to interact with them (what interface: LPT, GPIO, etc..) and at what "pin" for that interface. The DB doesn't care whether the switch is currently on or off. Thus I plan to have the following table:

```
switches
--------
<<pk>> name
interface
pin
```

Now, if the end-user wants to turn off "Light1" or "Light2" they can do so while being agnostic to what type of switch it is or where it's wired.

Where my problem/question comes is I also want to be able to create "groups" to turn on/off multiple related switches at once. Each group will have a unique name (preferably also unique from any name of an individual switch). A switch may exist in zero, one or many groups. Though, my understanding is it would be a bad practice to store a "list" in a column of a SQL table.

An example of groups (using lights as an example), is I may have a group called "Lights" that contains the name of every light switch. I may also have a group named "KitchenLights" which contains the name of every light switch in the kitchen. The expectation is the lists will be manually maintained if related switches are newly added or removed.

One approach that I was thinking is just added more columns to the "switches" table to describe what "type" of switch (light) and "where" it is (kitchen) -- but then the types groups would be "hard coded." If I later decided I wanted to group them by which floor they're on, it would be structure change to add a new column and code change.

So, what are the suggestions for how to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: Kindly tell about the database server you are using?

Comment: Muhammad, thank you for your support. I plan to use mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following approach:

```
create table switches
(name varchar(100) primary key,
 interface int,
 pin varchar(100));


Create table groups
( group_id int primary key,
group_name varchar (100));

Create table sub_group
( group_id int, 
switch_id varchar(100) ,
constraint groups_fk FOREIGN KEY (group_id) references groups(group_id),
constraint switches_fk FOREIGN KEY (switch_id ) references switches(name));
insert into switches values 
('Light1',123,'xyz'),
('Light2',456,'abcd'),
('Light3',789,'testpin');
insert into groups values
(1,'Group1'),
(2,'Group2'),
(3,'Group3');
insert into sub_group values 
( 1,'Light1'),(1,'Light2'),
(2,'Light1'),(2,'Light3');
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that's probably what I need.

The next question is if I am given group name and I want to get the 
switch details for every switch in that group, is the following the correct statement:

    select * from groups
    JOIN sub_group on sub_group.group_id = groups.group_id
    JOIN switches on sub_group.switch_id = switches.name
    where groups.group_name = 'Group1';

Comment: If my answer has solved your problem then kindly mark it as answer.